# Pip installing Tensorflow always fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

My environment setup:

- Python version: 3.8.3
- pip version: 20.2.4

Pip commands used:

- `pip install tensorflow`
- `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

The error I keep getting:

[image: Command Prompt Error]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is network issue. Happens due to incorrect network config/ simultaneous requests to the same outbound server. Try restarting PC and running commands in a fresh terminal one at a time. If it doesn't help it might eventually get fixed by flushing DNS cache:

1. Enter cmd in Run’s Open box and click OK to open the Command Prompt.
2. Input ipconfig /flushdns in the Prompt, and press the Enter key.
3. Restart your router after flushing DNS.

If issue still persists try [some other network related fixes.](https://windowsreport.com/existing-connection-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host/)

P.S. The error isnt because of versions as [tensorflow is available for python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804751/7212929). And it actually starts installing for you which signifies there is no versioning issue.